# Mapping temperature profiles with interpolation

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping

I have a script almost ready to plot temperature profiles taken every second day in a lake with interpolating the times not measured. But I cannot get it to run because "Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`". Can any of you help? The code looks like this:

```
p<-ggplot(Kill,aes(x=Day,y=Depth_minus))+
  geom_raster(aes(fill=Temperature))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low ="blue",high="red")+
  geom_contour(aes(z=Temperature),binwidth=2,colour="black",alpha=0.2)+
  geom_point(Kill,aes(x=Day,y=Depth),colour="black",size=3,alpha=1,shape=15)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(y="Depth (m)\n",x="\nDay of August",colour="Temperature (°C)")+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=20),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=18,colour="black"),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=20),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=18,colour="black"),
        axis.ticks=element_line(colour="black",size=1),
        axis.line=element_line(colour="black",size=1,linetype="solid"),
        legend.position="right",
        legend.text=element_text(colour="black",size=17),
        legend.title=element_text(colour="black",size=18))
p
```

Comment: Try with `geom_point(data = Kill, ...)`. The first argument of a geom is the mapping. If you pass the data you have to name the argument. However. As Kill is already the global data passed via ggplot you could remove it from geom_point.

Comment: Thank you stefan, that was the bug. Works now :)

Comment: Now, the plot looks okay, the isotherms are displayed every degree and the colours are right. However, there are no nice gradients between temperature values, but instead only squares with certain temperatures. How can I improve my code to get colour gradients instead of categories?